# What is the probabilistic counterpart of weighted K-Means

Tags: st.statistics

Gaussian mixture models (GMM) can be seen as the probabilistic counterparts of the k-means clustering algorithm. Weighted k-means takes a set of weighted samples and arranges the centroids according to weighted means of the data clusters, where the weights are the weights of the samples. I wonder if there is a GMM-like probabilistic counterpart of weighted k-means.

Answer (score 1):

[pKNN+AL](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/akapoor/papers/cvpr2009_active.pdf) (Jain and Kapoor, 2009) is a probabilistic modification of the KNN classifier. Given a set of points $\{x_1, \ldots, x_n\}$ from $\mathbb{R}^d$, labels $\{y_1, \ldots, y_n\}$ from $[1,C]$, and a Mercer kernel $K$, the probability of $x$ belonging to class $c$ is

$$\frac{\frac{1}{n_c} \sum_{\{i : y_i = c\}} K(x, x_i)}{\sum_{t=1}^C \frac{1}{n_t} \sum_{\{i : y_i = c\}} K(x, x_i)}$$

where $n_c$ is the number of $x_i$ that belong to class $c$. It is also an [active learning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supervised_learning#Active_Learning) algorithm and comes with a [MATLAB implementation](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/akapoor/cvpr2009/).

Comment: I think our notion of the term weight is different. The weight $w_i$ of sample $x_i$ in the sense of weighted k-means is a measure for the importance of $x_i$ for the entire clustering. The weights are fixed and given with the data set a priori. Thus the k-means centriods are centered above clusters the samples of which have high weights. If there are clusters with low weights, they are ignored. 

Answer (score 0):

How about Clara, or even PAM? I think Clara is an interesting mix between k-means and PAM.

Comment: How do Clara and PAM account for the weight of each sample?

Comment: Changing PAM by adding a multiplier should not be difficult. 

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for a GMM with weighted samples?  Please see [my answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/19011/estimate-gaussian-mixture-density-from-a-set-of-weighted-samples/20579#20579)